# How can I solve "incompatible library version" problem with ruby 2.7.4 on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, mysql2

Hello it's my first question here.
I'm trying to build a redmine system on my server but facing some problems.

my system -  ubuntu20.04 + nginx1.18 + mariadb10.3.30 + ruby2.7.4 + redmine4.2.2 / use rbenv to install ruby

when I'm trying to connect the redmine server, I got this error

```
App 716658 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: libruby.so.2.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /opt/redmine/vendor/cache/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

so I did
`cd /usr/lib`

`ln -s /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/libruby.so.2.7 libruby.so.2.7`

then incompatible library version error occurred

```
App 722799 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: incompatible library version - /opt/redmine/vendor/cache/ruby/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

I tried `gem pristine --all` but not worked.

How can I solve this problem? so many errors occurred so I guess there is a problem on my setting.

**gem env**

```
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.25
 - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.4 (2021-07-07 patchlevel 191) [x86_64-linux]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
 - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/ruby
 - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin
 - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
 - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/etc
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
 - GEM PATHS:
    - /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
    - /root/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
 - SHELL PATH:
    - /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin
    - /root/.rbenv/libexec
    - /root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
    - /root/.rbenv/shims
    - /root/.rbenv/bin
    - /usr/local/sbin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /usr/bin
    - /sbin
    - /bin
    - /usr/games
    - /usr/local/games
    - /snap/bin
```

**bundle env**

```
Bundler       2.2.25
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby          2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23704a01d34bd79d09dc37897e00922a) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/etc
RubyGems      3.2.25
  Gem Home    /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  Gem Path    /root/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  User Home   /root
  User Path   /root/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  Bin Dir     /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.25.1
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.1.2-61-g585ed84
  chruby      not installed
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2021-07-30
Git SHA           7f0f257c7a
Released Version  true
```

Comment: You said that the error happened when you "connect to the server". Should we assume that you have the server installed and that it launches without errors? And it's only when you request a page that it errors? Also, of course, do you have the mysql2 gem installed - that's what's not being found.

Comment: Yes there is server and this redmine server_name is https://redmine.kinicaremom.net , I want to see the first page of redmine but it's not working. I request a page but there is error so I see log on /var/log/nginx/error.log . I checked `gem list` and found mysql2 (0.5.3).

Comment: Are you sure that the version of mysql2 you have specified is compatible with your version of ruby?

Comment: I checked https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2/versions/0.5.3 and there mysql2 0.5.3 REQUIRED RUBY VERSION: >= 2.0.0 so I think my ruby version 2.7.4 is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have configured bundler (a gem version manager for Ruby projects) to install the gems for Redmine in a different location from the usual system gems, namely to `/opt/redmine/vendor/cache`.

As such, the usual `gem` commands will not touch those bundler-installed gems since `gem` does not know about them. To re-install all bundler managed gems, you can instead run the following command within your Redmine directory (i/e/ the directory containing the `Gemfile`:

```
bundle pristine
```

This is effectively the same as `gem pristine --all` but just for the bundler-managed gems. See [the documentation](https://bundler.io/v2.2/man/bundle-pristine.1.html) for details.

Comment: Good call, Holger. The easiest way to have done this IME is to issue a `bundle install` when you're in the wrong directory (here, it looks like `/root/`) instead of `bundle install --system`. (Although, personally, I never do that and always install gems into the specific project's directory.)

Comment: I tried `bundle pristine` on `/opt/redmine` but it's not working TT

Comment: You could also try to delete (or move out of the way) your `/opt/redmine/vendor/cache/ruby` directory and install gems anew with `bundle install`