# Trouble while setting up redmine - rvmsudo throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, redmine

I am trying to setup the latest redmine-5.0.5.

Here is the step which is giving me an error.

```
vboxuser@itvb:/srv/redmine-5.0.5$ rvmsudo /usr/sbin/passenger-status 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    14: from /usr/sbin/passenger-status:38:in `<main>'
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:243:in `require_passenger_lib'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    11: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    10: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance_registry.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:243:in `require_passenger_lib'
     8: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
     7: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
     6: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:243:in `require_passenger_lib'
     4: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
     3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
     2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/json.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require': incompatible library version - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/strscan-3.0.6/lib/strscan.so (LoadError)
vboxuser@itvb:/srv/redmine-5.0.5$
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

As mentioned in the link by anothermh I tried :

```
bundle pristine
```

in the /srv/redmine-5.0.5 directory.

I am still getting the same error in the rvmsudo incantation.

Here are the results of ***gem env*** and ***bundle env***.

```
/srv/redmine-5.0.5$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.0 (2020-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/vboxuser/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: 
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/vboxuser/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
```

```
/srv/redmine-5.0.5$ bundle env
## Environment
```

```
Bundler             2.4.10
  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby                3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff214687a5e12c3eb57d056665741e734c188) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path         /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby
  Config Dir        /etc
RubyGems            3.2.3
  Gem Home          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0
  Gem Path          /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  User Home         /home/vboxuser
  User Path         /home/vboxuser/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
  Bin Dir           /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin
Tools               
  Git               not installed
  RVM               1.29.12 (latest)
  rbenv             not installed
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2023-03-27
Git SHA           7ffdec80d0
Released Version  true
```

### Bundler settings

```
without
  Set for your local app (/srv/redmine-5.0.5/.bundle/config): [:development, :test]
  Set for the current user (/home/vboxuser/.bundle/config): [:development, :test]
```

### Gemfile

#### Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '>= 2.5.0', '< 3.2.0'
gem 'bundler', '>= 1.12.0'

gem 'rails', '6.1.7.2'
gem 'globalid', '~> 0.4.2' if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0')
gem 'rouge', '~> 3.28.0'
gem 'request_store', '~> 1.5.0'
gem 'mini_mime', '~> 1.1.0'
gem "actionpack-xml_parser"
gem 'roadie-rails', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '~> 2.2.0' : '~> 3.0.0')
gem 'marcel'
gem "mail", "~> 2.7.1"
gem 'csv', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'nokogiri', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '~> 1.12.5' : '~> 1.13.10')
gem "rexml", require: false if Gem.ruby_version >= Gem::Version.new('3.0')
gem 'i18n', '~> 1.10.0'
gem 'rbpdf', '~> 1.21.0'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 2.3.0'
gem 'net-smtp', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'net-imap', '~> 0.2.2'
gem 'net-pop', '~> 0.1.1'
# Rails 6.1.6.1 does not work with Pysch 3.0.2, which is installed by default with Ruby 2.5. See https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/45590
gem 'psych', '>= 3.1.0' if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0')

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]

# TOTP-based 2-factor authentication
gem 'rotp', '>= 5.0.0'
gem 'rqrcode'

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
  gem 'net-ldap', '~> 0.17.0'
end

# Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file
group :minimagick do
  gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.11.0'
end

# Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby
# ToDo: Remove common_mark group when common_mark is decoupled from markdown. See defect (#36892) for more details.
gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.5.1', groups: [:markdown, :common_mark]

# Optional CommonMark support, not for JRuby
group :common_mark do
  gem "html-pipeline", "~> 2.13.2"
  gem "commonmarker", (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6.0') ? '0.21.0' : '~> 0.23.8')
  gem "sanitize", "~> 6.0"
  gem 'deckar01-task_list', '2.3.2'
end

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database
# configuration file
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")
if File.exist?(database_file)
  yaml_config = ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result
  database_config = YAML.respond_to?(:unsafe_load) ? YAML.unsafe_load(yaml_config) : YAML.load(yaml_config)
  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
  if adapters.any?
    adapters.each do |adapter|
      case adapter
      when 'mysql2'
        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.5.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /postgresql/
        gem "pg", "~> 1.2.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /sqlite3/
        gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      when /sqlserver/
        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 2.1.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", "~> 6.1.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      else
        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")
      end
    end
  else
    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")
  end
else
  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem "yard"
end

group :test do
  gem "rails-dom-testing"
  gem 'mocha', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7.0') ? ['>= 1.4.0', '< 2.0.0'] : '>= 1.4.0')
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.21.2', :require => false
  gem "ffi", platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
  # For running system tests
  gem 'puma', (Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7') ? '< 6.0.0' : '>= 0')
  gem 'capybara', (if Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.6')
                     '~> 3.35.3'
                   elsif Gem.ruby_version < Gem::Version.new('2.7')
                     '~> 3.36.0'
                   else
                     '~> 3.38.0'
                   end)
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 3.142.7"
  gem 'webdrivers', '4.6.1', require: false
  # RuboCop
  gem 'rubocop', '~> 1.26.0'
  gem 'rubocop-performance', '~> 1.13.0'
  gem 'rubocop-rails', '~> 2.14.0'
end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")
if File.exist?(local_gemfile)
  eval_gemfile local_gemfile
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|
  eval_gemfile file
end

gem "webrick", "~> 1.7"
```

#### Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.7.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.7.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.2)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.7.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.2)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.7.2)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actionpack-xml_parser (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    actiontext (6.1.7.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.2)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
    activerecord (6.1.7.2)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
    activestorage (6.1.7.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.1)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    ast (2.4.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    capybara (3.38.0)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    chunky_png (1.4.0)
    commonmarker (0.23.8)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    crass (1.0.6)
    css_parser (1.14.0)
      addressable
    csv (3.2.6)
    deckar01-task_list (2.3.2)
      html-pipeline
    digest (3.1.1)
    docile (1.4.0)
    erubi (1.12.0)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    globalid (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    html-pipeline (2.13.2)
      activesupport (>= 2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    i18n (1.10.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    listen (3.8.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.19.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_magick (4.11.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    minitest (5.18.0)
    mocha (2.0.2)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.5)
    mysql2 (0.5.5)
    net-imap (0.2.3)
      digest
      net-protocol
      strscan
    net-ldap (0.17.1)
    net-pop (0.1.2)
      net-protocol
    net-protocol (0.2.1)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.3)
      net-protocol
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.10-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    parallel (1.22.1)
    parser (3.2.1.1)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
    public_suffix (5.0.1)
    puma (6.1.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.2)
    rack (2.2.6.4)
    rack-test (2.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (6.1.7.2)
      actioncable (= 6.1.7.2)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.7.2)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.7.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.2)
      actiontext (= 6.1.7.2)
      actionview (= 6.1.7.2)
      activejob (= 6.1.7.2)
      activemodel (= 6.1.7.2)
      activerecord (= 6.1.7.2)
      activestorage (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.7.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.5.0)
      loofah (~> 2.19, >= 2.19.1)
    railties (6.1.7.2)
      actionpack (= 6.1.7.2)
      activesupport (= 6.1.7.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rainbow (3.1.1)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rbpdf (1.21.1)
      htmlentities
      rbpdf-font (~> 1.19.0)
    rbpdf-font (1.19.1)
    redcarpet (3.5.1)
    regexp_parser (2.7.0)
    request_store (1.5.1)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    roadie (5.1.0)
      css_parser (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    roadie-rails (3.0.0)
      railties (>= 5.1, < 7.1)
      roadie (~> 5.0)
    rotp (6.2.2)
    rouge (3.28.0)
    rqrcode (2.1.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.0)
      rqrcode_core (~> 1.0)
    rqrcode_core (1.2.0)
    rubocop (1.26.1)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 3.1.0.0)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.8, < 3.0)
      rexml
      rubocop-ast (>= 1.16.0, < 2.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 3.0)
    rubocop-ast (1.28.0)
      parser (>= 3.2.1.0)
    rubocop-performance (1.13.3)
      rubocop (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
      rubocop-ast (>= 0.4.0)
    rubocop-rails (2.14.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.1)
      rubocop (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.13.0)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sanitize (6.0.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.12.0)
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    simplecov (0.21.2)
      docile (~> 1.1)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.11)
      simplecov_json_formatter (~> 0.1)
    simplecov-html (0.12.3)
    simplecov_json_formatter (0.1.4)
    sprockets (4.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    strscan (3.0.6)
    thor (1.2.1)
    timeout (0.3.2)
    tzinfo (2.0.6)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    unicode-display_width (2.4.2)
    webdrivers (4.6.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webrick (1.7.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    yard (0.9.28)
      webrick (~> 1.7.0)
    zeitwerk (2.6.7)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  actionpack-xml_parser
  addressable
  bundler (>= 1.12.0)
  capybara (~> 3.38.0)
  commonmarker (~> 0.23.8)
  csv (~> 3.2.0)
  deckar01-task_list (= 2.3.2)
  ffi
  html-pipeline (~> 2.13.2)
  i18n (~> 1.10.0)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  mail (~> 2.7.1)
  marcel
  mini_magick (~> 4.11.0)
  mini_mime (~> 1.1.0)
  mocha (>= 1.4.0)
  mysql2 (~> 0.5.0)
  net-imap (~> 0.2.2)
  net-ldap (~> 0.17.0)
  net-pop (~> 0.1.1)
  net-smtp (~> 0.3.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.13.10)
  puma
  rails (= 6.1.7.2)
  rails-dom-testing
  rbpdf (~> 1.21.0)
  redcarpet (~> 3.5.1)
  request_store (~> 1.5.0)
  rexml
  roadie-rails (~> 3.0.0)
  rotp (>= 5.0.0)
  rouge (~> 3.28.0)
  rqrcode
  rubocop (~> 1.26.0)
  rubocop-performance (~> 1.13.0)
  rubocop-rails (~> 2.14.0)
  rubyzip (~> 2.3.0)
  sanitize (~> 6.0)
  selenium-webdriver (~> 3.142.7)
  simplecov (~> 0.21.2)
  tzinfo-data
  webdrivers (= 4.6.1)
  webrick (~> 1.7)
  yard

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   2.4.10
```

I tried : `bundle pristine` in the /srv/redmine-5.0.5 folder as suggested in the post pointed to by anothermh.

I also tried adding : `PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/wrappers/ruby`

to `redmine.conf` and restarting Apache2.

I read this here : https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/67766

Both these did not work.

@GChuf following your comment I did this:

```
vboxuser@itvb:~$ sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install
What would you like to validate?
Use <space> to select.
If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

 ‣ ⬢  Passenger itself
   ⬡  Apache

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

 * Checking whether this Passenger install is in PATH... ✓
 * Checking whether there are no other Passenger installations... ✓

Everything looks good. :-)
vboxuser@itvb:~$ rvmsudo passenger status
Phusion Passenger(R) Standalone is not running, according to PID file /home/vboxuser/passenger.3000.pid
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve "incompatible library version" problem with ruby 2.7.4 on ubuntu 20.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639242/how-can-i-solve-incompatible-library-version-problem-with-ruby-2-7-4-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Is passenger running? Does "rvmsudo passenger status" (no hyphen) work?